# SQL Server permission denied on linked server object

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 database servers for simplicity server A and server B. The current process user has access to server A database db1, from ssms I can insert into tables e.g Members.

```
 USE db1
 GO

 INSERT INTO dbo.Members(mem_num) values (1);
 --Query executed successfully (1 row(s) affected).
```

On Server B, Server A is a linked object with the name A.
so same user I try the following query

```
 INSERT INTO [A].[db1].[dbo].[Members](mem_num) values (1);
 --Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
 --The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'Members', database 'db1', schema 'dbo'.
```

I'm not sure what the issue is as the following query works fine

```
 SELECT mem_num FROM [A].[db1].[dbo].[Members]
 --Query executed successfully. 1 rows
```

The SQL servers are both running win server 2008, sql server 2008 and use windows authentication. any ideas would be awesome.

Comment: How have you created the link?

Comment: Check the security options on the linked server properties.

Comment: I'm not sure I will ever know, as these were client databases, since posting my contract expired with client and I now longer have access. However the best possible solution that I could find was to use impersonation on the linked server, as I didn't have permission to make the needed change it was raised to the client's database team with that as a suggestion. If I ever find out I will update this post.